# How to model a choke on LTSpice?

Tags: power-supply, inductor, ltspice

I am simulating a power supply on LTSpice which has two filter chokes (as shown below). The nameplate on these chokes has the following information.

First choke - *DC Filter Reactor, 4 terminal, 40µH, 190ADC*

Second choke - *Output Filter Inductor, 20µH, 400A*

[image: First Choke]

[image: Second Choke]

Is this the same as modeling two separate inductors in LTSpice as shown below?

[image: LTSpice Simulation Model]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you placed the inductors with the correct polarities, and since the dots are shown it (probably) means that you have a coupling statement, somewhere. I can't see it, though, but if you have it, then you're set. If not, then you need to add it (that's what the Z means in your 1st schematic): press <kbd>S</kbd> and type the expression, something like in the picture below:

[image: coupling]

I haven't used any values for the inductors. Note that, by default, there is a 1 mΩ series resistance, but which is set to zero when the coupling is added. If you need it, don't forget to add it manually.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Does 40 uH from the nameplate correspond to both L1 and L2 to be 40 uH or does it mean that L1 is 20 uH and L2 is 20 uH?

Comment: @Engineer Both inductors will have 40 uH, yes. The coupling will not necessarily be `0.99`, that was for exemplification, only. But it's a reasonably good figure.